# Gem dependency hell installing redmine with CRM plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, redmine

I was installing a clean Redmine 3.0 with CRM plugin on a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 14.04LTS. I succeeded with redmine and a minor plugin, but the CRM one has hit me with this:

```
# bundle install --without development test RAILS_ENV=production
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and 
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root 
users on this machine.

Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using `source` more
than once without a block is a security risk, and may result in installing 
unexpected gems. To resolve this warning, use a block to indicate which gems 
should come from the secondary source. To upgrade this warning to an error, run 
`bundle config disable_multisource true`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "i18n":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.0) ruby depends on
      actionpack (= 4.2.0) ruby depends on
        activesupport (= 4.2.0) ruby depends on
          i18n (~> 0.7) ruby

    money (~> 5.1.0) ruby depends on
      i18n (~> 0.6.0) ruby
```

I installed i18n 0.6.0 and 0.7.0, didn't fix:

```
# gem list --local | grep i18n
i18n (0.7.0, 0.6.0)
```

I tried removing the Gemfile.lock and using bundler (`bundle update && bundle install`) again, same result.

I have no idea how to proceed with this issue. I know very little of ruby, gems and bundler and searching has failed me. Help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the CRM plugin from [redminecrm.com](http://www.redminecrm.com/projects/crm/pages/1) with Redmine 3 right now.

At the time of writing, the plugin is only compatible to Redmine 2.x. While the plugin will probably get updated by the authors, it is not yet compatible with Redmine 3.0.

Generally, you should not expect plugins to magically continue to work across major version updates. Especially when there was a major update recently, many plugins will not yet be compatible to the new Redmine version. If you need the plugins, you might be able to use an older version, e.g. Redmine 2.6, until all the plugins you need are updated.

You always have to check if a plugin is compatible to the Redmine version you intend to use.

Comment: Well, checked with another plugin that was redmine 2.x only it worked on 3.0. I was hoping that this one might also.